# unwanted grid appeared in render viewport

Tags: rendering, settings

[image: as the image shows there is a unwanted grid background in my render viewport]

Does anyone know how to get rid of it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: [I recommend taking screenshots of your screen instead of photographs](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/) Taking photographs of your own screen looks really unprofessional and even silly in pretty much all contexts and sometimes makes it a lot harder for people who attempt to help because it's not always possible to see essential information in low quality incomplete images with reflections.

Answer (score 1):

This "grid" is here to tell you the background will be transparent when rendering. You can set the background not to be transparent in the Render Properties like below :

[image: background transparent settings]

This will remove the grid you have in your viewport with shading set to "Rendered"

Comment: Thank you so much!!!